# ODBC Driver mismatch VS

Tags: visual-studio, odbc

I am getting an error message about mismatch when trying to connect to ODBC driver in Visual studio.
I've already tested both versions(32 and 64).
When I try with 32 I get this message:
**[DataSource.Error] ODBC: ERROR [IM014] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver (32-bit) and Application (64-bit).**
With 64 this:
**[DataSource.Error] ODBC: ERROR [IM014] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver (64-bit) and Application (32-bit).**
Does not make sense!!
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver (32-bit) and Application (64-bit)**
It seems you're dealing with a mismatch between the bit versions of Power BI Desktop and the ODBC Data Source (DSN) driver. To fix this, ensure that both Power BI and the DSN driver are of the same bit version. This alignment is crucial for proper compatibility.